# On the Discretization of Energy Levels

Tags: classical-mechanics

We consider a system of "n" particles whose total energy E and net momentum $\vec{P}$ are fixed are fixed.There no net force on the system(assumed)

$$\Sigma \epsilon_i= E$$
$$\Sigma\vec{p_i}=\vec{P}$$
For an individual particle its momentnum and energy remain constant for the time $\tau$,the relaxation time(average time between successive collisions----a constant). That's an extra constraint for each particle
[Radiational energy density at some point is assumed to be constant for some physically small time interval]

All that seem to indicate that classical theories  favor the discretization of energy levels in the equilibrium state.
It is important to note that for each particle to satisfy on the mass shell
 condition we should have:
$$\epsilon_i^2-p_i^2=m_0^2c^4$$
The above equation is frame invariant.Any theoretical speculation considering energy and momentum independent of each other should correspond to what we understand by "off the mass shell" situation
An orbiting electron in an atom ,so far as the classical theories are concerned , should radiate energy. But it can also receive energy form other particles.The net radiation from a block of iron at constant temperature is zero.This should favor the discretization of the electronic  orbits in the atoms in the expected manner.

[For a cluster of charged particles one  should take into account the electromagnetic  potential energy of the system( a closed system ) due to the presence of charges and currents.This energy for the system should be considered  constant for our model]

Should we use intuition(commonsense classical theories ) to interpret QM with the understanding that the results of observation should not change in view of the system interacting with the measuring instrument and that QM will be no less useful to human activity?

[Some points to examine have been placed on the following link:

http://independent.academia.edu/AnamitraPalit/Papers/1892195/Fourier_Transforms_in_QM_Gravitons_and_Otherons_

The document may be downloaded though you get a message that conversion is going on]]

Comment: Just think of a pair of particles participating in an elastic collision.You don't get arbitrary solutions satisfying the equations involved.Now you may extend your thinking to ten particles and then to ten million particles involved in an elastic collision(net force on the system being zero). The relaxation time and its constant nature become important when you are considering a huge number of particles.

Comment: A Relevant Paper:http://independent.academia.edu/AnamitraPalit/Papers/1889577/Fourier_Transforms_in_QM_Gravitons_Speculated_Revised_

Comment: $F(E,p,x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t}f(x,t)e^{ia(Et-px)}dxdt$----(A).$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-ipxf)e^{ia(Et-px)}$ Again $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{-\infty}^{t}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-iEf)e^{ia(Et-px)}$. If $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$ favors $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-iap=0$ =>$(x,t)=Ae^{iapx}$. Again, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$ should favor $f(x,t)=Be^{-iaEt}$. Finally we obtain $f(x,t)=Ae^{-ia(Et-px)}$--(B)which is a solution of the Klien Gordon equation.

Comment: Relation (A) becomes the Fourier transform when both x and t tend to infinity.Using (B) in (A) and allowing x and t to tend to $\infty$,we obtain:$F(E,p)=Const\times \delta(E-E_0)\delta(p-p_0)$
Integration of the last formula on the (E,p) domain counts the number of (E0,p0) modes present.If we divide this by the total number of possible modes we obtain a probability picture

Comment: Regarding Relation B in the scond last  comment:(1) It satisfies the Klein Gordon Relation. (2)For the invariance of the exponential part the Lorentz transformations are a suitable candidate provided "a" is a universal constant.(3)Energy and momentum are suitable choices for E and p if Et and px are dimensionally identical.(4)The psi indicated by relation (B)is periodic nature associated with a probability picture.

Comment: We may write directly,$F(E,P)=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}f(x,t)e^{ia(Et-px)}dxdt$ and use the facts $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0$ to arrive the results in the previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is nonsense--- the "quantization of energy" you are referring to in classical theories is not a quantization at all, it is equipartition. It is only true that independent degrees of freedom have an average energy which is roughly quantized in classical mechanics.

You can't make a classical equilibrium between a field and an atom, because the field always has infinitely many degrees of freedom, and the atom finitely many. So the atom goes to the classical ground state, the electrons sit on top of the nucleus, and the field jitters thermally infinitesimally (because the finite energy is all sucked to the smallest wavelength modes).

This is called the ultraviolet catastrophe, and it dooms attempt to explain quantum behavior from a classical theory.

The simplest argument against a modified classical mechanics reproducing quantum mechanics is that quantum mechanics introduces a dimensional constant $\hbar$ which is not there in the classical limit. So if you start with the classical limit, you have to explain what sets the scale $\hbar$. This was debated in the early quarter of the twentieth century, and these ideas do not work.

Comment: Maxwell' Boltzman's Distribution is a unimodal bell shaped one assigning the highest probability to the mean speed of the entire system of oscillators at least in an approximate way.The mean speed of the highest frequency oscillator is much greater than the said mean value pertaining to the entire mass of oscillators.Any effort to assign the largest strength to the oscillators on the higher frequency side would be a big mistake even from the classical point of view. Maxwellian distribution of momenta,incidentally, remain valid even in a potential field.

Comment: Let's go into a simple treatment:The number of modes of frequency $\nu_n$ for the first octant of a sphere of radius  "n":$N=\frac{1}{8}\frac{4\pi}{3} n^3=\frac{\pi}{6}(\frac{2L}{c})^3 \nu_n^2$---(1)Therefore number of modes on the interval$(\nu_n,\nu_n+d \nu_n)$:$dN=\frac{4\pi}{c^3}L^2{\mu_n}^2 d\mu_n$. N and dN correspond to possible modes and not to the actual modes that may be realized consistently if the energy of the system ,its total momentum etc remain unchanged.These factors asre considered in the derivation of the Maxwell -Boltzman distribution.

Comment: @AnamitraPalit: The number of modes is _infinite_ you are finding density of modes. The infinite number of modes means an infinite energy. This is the ultraviolet catastrophe, there is nothing more to say.

Comment: Let's consider the example of a string stretched between a pair of fixed points. You may pluck the string at some point suppressing a multitude of modes. Still you have an infinite number of modes left in the oscillation. Do the highest or rather the higher frequency modes have as large an amplitude as the fundamental?

Comment: You may think in terms of the Fourier decomposition of a particular function represented by the oscillating string.For a physical problem the constant coefficients in  the Fourier series should be of reasonable values so that the series does not blow up. You may have an infinite number of terms(modes) leading to a finite values of energy for the system

Comment: @AnamitraPalit: Yes--- the string analogy is perfect. When you pluck the string, it will eventually decay so that all the frequency modes have the same amplitude on average--- this is the thermal state. All other states are unstable to this. If your string has random density perturbations, or is attached to thermal walls, then it will eventually decay to be stationary, and then all modes will have the same (infinitesimal) energy on average. The series will blow up for a continuous string, it will not blow up for a string made of atoms. This is the ultraviolet catastrophe.

Comment: @RonMaimon: I just want to add, that one doesn't need quantum mechanics to solve the ultraviolet catastrophe. If one models the string as a chain of particles connected with springs, then the system is fine.

Comment: @Fabian: The problem is that this fix doesn't work for electromagnetic waves, since for colder systems, the discreteness scale would have to become enormous, and temperature dependent. This was all worked out in the 1900-1910 period, and QM is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: @RonMaimon: you don't have to convince me about QM (I am convinced). I just wanted to point out that classical atoms with some kind of spring force render to problem of a vibrating string well-defined.

Comment: The main problem with EM is that the atoms (the center of mass of the atoms) would provide a reference system much like aether.

Comment: Uncertainty Principle from the Classical Ideas:$[Cov(X,Y)]^2=\rho^2 \sigma_x \sigma_y$. X ans Y are two variables that have an association with each other for example the position coordinate $x$ and momentum $p_x$ in the process of a measurement $Cov(x,y)\ne 0$ implies $\sigma_x \sigma_y \ne 0$ that is,$\sigma_x \times \sigma_y=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\rho^2}= A{\;\;}positive{\;\;} Quantity$.For a precise measurement of X or Y $Cov(X,Y)=0$ leading to an independence of the two variables concerned.The above classical facts indicate towards an uncertainty relation

Comment: Edit :1.$Cov(X,Y)=\rho{\;} \sigma_x \sigma_y $ 2.We have,$\sigma_x \sigma_y=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\rho} >  0$ if the variables X and Y have some dependence. 3.For a precise measurement I have implied X=const or Y= const . For such a situation we have $Cov(X,Y)=0$ and  the variables lose their dependence or association.

Comment: $\sigma_x \sigma_y=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\rho} greater{\;} than{\;} zero$. I have written it here since in my previous comment the greater than sign is looking like a right arrow.How do you write greater than in Latex?(I know how to write greater than equal to in latex,\ge?

Comment: A measurement performed on the state of a system is an $operation$ on the system intended to obtain a value for some physical quantity. For measuring different physical quantities we need to perform, in a natural way,  different types of measurement to be represented by distinct $operators$. This commonsense idea is in tune with the formal technique in QM:Operator acting on the $\psi-function$ generates the eignvalues,ie, the numbers used to denote specific physical properties.